# What's wrong with this nftables rule?

Tags: nftables

I'm playing around with nftables a little bit and I've set up this rule to block all traffic coming from 192.168.0.29.

The curious result, however, is that it blocks the pings, but I can still SSH from that respective host, in spite of the rule.

```
sudo nft rule add mytable mychain ip saddr 192.168.0.29 drop
```

What's wrong with this? 
nft list ruleset

```
table ip mytable {
chain mychain {
    type filter hook input priority 0; policy accept;
    ip saddr 192.168.0.29 drop
}
```

}
Edit: Now I've blocked the whole subnet, with the same result. SSH is still standing, for some reason.

Comment: Add the whole configuration to your question, i.e. the output of `nft list ruleset`

Comment: Also, ipv6 maybe?

Comment: @HaukeLaging that IS my whole configuration. I mean, like I said in the title, I don't have a setup. I'm just feeling it out right now, playing around with nft. But I'm still puzzled as to why ssh connections are allowed. I gave the rule a progressively lower priority (down to 380), and it's still the same.

Comment: @TomYan That's what I thought, and then it just slipped my mind. Thanks for reminding me - I'm looking into it right now. It's actually likely that it might use ipv6 since ipv4 is blocked. Darn it

Comment: @TomYan it was ip6. I could see the connection in ss and lsof. I set up another table with a rule to drop all ip6 connections, and sure enough, things were now as expected.